# How to sort an array based on pairs in 8086 assembly

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86-16

Say I have an array defined by:

```
array DW 1,1,3,0,3,3,4,4,-1
```

The array is terminated by -1, how would I be able to sort the array in pairs of descending order based on the first number in the pair (if first number is the same then it's sorted by the second number) as such:

> 4, 4; 3, 3; 3, 0; 1, 1;

Comment: Any way you wish? What is unclear/problematic to you? Can you design some algorithm? Write some parts of that? Is there something particular too tricky for you to think of?

Comment: But the way you defined the problem, you can basically sort the array in source like you did, i.e.:

`array DW 4,4,3,3,3,0,1,1,-1` - done.

Comment: The problem is that I can sort the elements within the array individually but don't know to sort the numbers as pairs

Comment: so break it down, what is the difference... first, all array manipulations (swaps of elements) will be done per 32 bits, pointers will advance by 32 bits, etc.. because single element is 32 bits. The check for terminating element is somewhat tricky, as that one is only 16b `-1` value, but you can scan for that one once at start and remember count of full 32b elements. Now whether element A belong ahead of element B (predicate) is function of `(A.low16b>B.low16) || ((A.low16b==B.low16) && (A.high16b>B.high16))` which translated into asm and optimized will be actually just few instructions.

Comment: rest of it is identical with single word element sorting, in principle. (keep in mind all values in computer are encoded in bits, so if you can tell where the information resides, like in your case `dw 1,0` creates 32 bits in memory, when viewed as bytes it's: `01 00 00 00` - so if you move around those four bytes, you did move "pair of values" ... the CPU doesn't care about higher abstraction interpretation of those bytes, if it's pair of words, or quartet of bytes, or single double-word, you can work with them as four bytes at one point, and then suddenly treat them as two words, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> array DW 1,1, 3,0, 3,3, 4,4, -1
> ```

The first number in each pair of word-sized numbers is the most significant for your task.
Each of these pairs can be seen as a dword, but on x86 (little endian) the first word will be the least significant. That's just the opposite of what you need. What if you temporarily swapped the words? Then you could sort the array as normal dwords.

1. Swap
2. Sort these **dwords** normally. (Beware terminator is still **word**)
3. Swap.

This could be the *swap* procedure (32-bit):

```
Swap:
    mov ebx, array
    jmp First
Next:
    rol dword [ebx], 16
    add ebx, 4
First:
    cmp word [ebx], -1
    jne Next
    ret
```

This could be the *swap* procedure (16-bit):

```
Swap:
    mov  bx, array
    jmp  First
Next:
    xchg ax, [bx+2]
    mov  [bx], ax
    add  bx, 4
First:
    mov  ax, [bx]
    cmp  ax, -1
    jne  Next
    ret
```

A solution where you do these pre-swap and post-swap operations *within the dword sorting algorithm* would be just as easy.